# Editing entry without creating a new revision in particular scenario. is this possible?

Tags: craft3, craft-features, revisions

I'm updating particular field in "A" section whenever a new entry is created in "B" section. In this scenario I don't want revision to be created for "A" section. Is this possible in craft CMS to avoid revision in editing entry?